# Key specs of USB Flash Drives used for saving game data

Tags: xbox-360

Is there anything special I should look for when purchasing a USB flash drive to store game profile data?

For example, when browsing the online stores, there are numerous 16GB flash drives out there and I want to make sure the one I purchase will work with the 360, but don't want to spend the extra $ to get the xbox branded drive.

I have one drive that's been sitting around the house that I've tried that seems to fit the minimum requirements, but when formatting it to use on my 360 I get the 'Can't configure' error.

Is there a compatibility list available somewhere? I found one list, but it appears to be for the original xbox on a linix forum.

Basically I'm not concerned about getting a drive that is too small, I just don't want to purchase one that, for some reason, is not compatible with the 360 or that I have to pay the extra markup for some pretty logos on the casing.

---

Edit: Was getting the 'Can't configure' error. 'Your device cannot be used with the USB storage device due to data loss and performance issues.'

Drive works great in Windows so I want to make sure to avoid this with the drive I purchase.

Comment: This is possibly borderline off-topic. Might be better suited for superuser.

Comment: @JN W this SE is suppose to encompass everything to do with video games including video game consoles, SU has a strict policy against consoles, so I think it belongs here if anywhere

Comment: @Earlz Fair enough. I know we're all sorting out what's appropriate right now anyway. I'll leave it up to the community as a whole.

Comment: I think the question should be reworded to something like "What are important specs for a USB flash drive used to store Xbox 360 gram profiles?" or something that is more specific than "USB Flash Drives". I can't edit or else I'd do it.

Comment: @michael, I updated the title and clarified the question a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the USB drive you choose is between 1GB and 16GB storage size. Not knowing which error you received, I'm not sure how best to advise you. Here are some links that may help you though.

- [XBox's USB Storage Overview](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/storage)
- [How to configure your USB drive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981974)

Also, don't buy the 360 branded USB drive. It is ridiculously overpriced!

Comment: I'm getting the 'can't configure' error. I agree, I don't want to buy the 360 branded drive with the crazy markup.

Comment: You'll have to use a different USB drive then I think. [Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981976/) the troubleshooting page for the error, but I think it's likely you may be just need a different one if you've already gone through the steps on the on configuration page I listed.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you definitely want to make sure you have enough storage space. Nothing will be worse than trying to save your game, but not having enough space.

However, speed may also be a factor. I used to believe that all USB sticks were created equal in terms of speed. I thought all USB 2.0 sticks were equally fast. Then I went online and saw some sticks being reviewed much better than others. I won't say where or which ones, so that nobody will think I am a shill.

In summary, I was very skeptical and bought the supposedly much faster USB sticks because they were only slightly more expensive. They were no joke. The sticks actually were faster. I can put them in the same computer in the same port, and you don't even need a benchmark. I can write and read files to and from these sticks at a significantly faster speed than the other ones I own. The progress bars on the file transfer move way faster, every single time on all brands of computer with all sizes of file. There's no mistaking it.

Also, some USB sticks are far more durable than others. If you are running around LAN parties, or between friend's houses, you might want to get one that is rubberized or metal, instead of cheap plastic. If it breaks, you lose your save games! Maybe you should get two sticks, to have a backup. Also, maybe get one with a lanyard so that you are less likely to lose it in the first place.

Comment: upvoted for mentioning speed as a key factor.