# In what ways will 4GB limit my Xbox usage?

Tags: kinect

Microsoft recently announced that "Kinect bundle" that includes Kinect and Xbox 4GB. The price is good, I'm thinking of getting one - but I have two questions:

1. In what ways 4GB would limit my Xbox usage?
2. Will I be able to extend the storage if needed, either using internal or external storage?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 4GB refers to a 4GB memory unit for the system. You use the storage for saved games, user profiles, downloads from Xbox Live, and "downloading" a game disk to your Xbox for faster loading. The only thing you would be missing out on that really matters is space for demos, videos, and other content from Xbox Live, as you won't have much space for them.  Game demos are several GB each, so the built-in 4GB won't hold many.

The upside is that there are several choices to upgrade the space in your system. USB thumb drives can be used for storage space in an Xbox 360.  You can buy 16GB flash drives from ~$30 any more, so that's one way you could go. Another method is to buy one of the internal Xbox hard drives. [According Aaron Greenberg, via Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/07/20/kinect-bundled-with-slim-4gb-xbox-360-arcade-for-300-new-conso/), 'this 4GB unit "absolutely does have that expansion bay that we have the opportunity to use in the future."'  So you will be able to buy any of the Xbox 360 S-capable hard drives to put in your expansion slot.

Comment: USB flash drive is a good solution. More here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3140/usb-flash-drives

Comment: Won't using a USB drive be incredibly, tortiously slow?

Comment: 4GB refers to storage not "memory unit", edit?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "4GB memory unit" is the terminology the Xbox team uses in the system for the 4GB integrated flash memory bank. I used to have an Arcade that showed it as "MU", meaning memory unit. I don't have it anymore, but I don't think they've changed terminology.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing "wrong" with it is the 4GB disk (not all of that will be usable - some is used for the OS and such). I have a 120GB Elite, and I love that I can install/copy games to the hard drive. This makes the Xbox run much quieter, and generally speeds up loading times.

It's also nice not to worry about deleting DLC and downloaded games (even though there is the option to re-download them). More space is generally better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 4 GB console. I have plenty of games through the Marketplace and yet i can't play them all. Some other games will also lack features: I just bought Forza 4 for 59$ and, to my disappointment, there are no replays available...

4 GB are good if you don't want to download content and save games.

Comment: Is this an answer or a rant?

Answer (score 0):

The limits you will encounter are as follows;
Downloading content from Xbox Live or disk, games on demand for example; Destiny is 6.8GB to download as a full game and can only be ran from a HDD. Meaning USB won't cut it.
Demos range from under a gigabyte(GB) to the size of the game disk(i.e, arcade demos are the same as the full version in size and are meerly activated and registered to the Xbox.
You can download all your C.D's to your Xbox, they will be compressed, though once again HDD only.
The larger HDD will cost you around $100-$170AUD to buy later, though in the deal above the one your looking at you get the larger HDD and another controller and a game or two for the extra $100-$150. So if you get that, sell the game and controller for 50.
Disks can be downloaded to run off the Xbox as long as the disk is in the tray, and the first thing to go is generally the disk drive if you play for long periods or music games like guitar hero.
Streaming movies through live will be fine, though if you want to buy and download them then keep in mind movies are around 6GB in size generally.
USB storage is limited to 32GB for any size of USB over 32GB too.
I'll add more if it crosses my mind.